# How to stub HTTP request on Mechanize in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mechanize, webmock

I have some codebase like this, and I wanna use rspec test favicon_href, but as you like, the favicon_href will call the page function, I know I can mock page function, but for this stage I wanna mock the HTTP request from the given url, so I use WebMock gem's syntax to stub HTTP request, but it seems WebMock is not compatibility with Mechanize, it always show the error in the below despite I relleay have done the stub, anyone know how can solve it or any gem can stub HTTP request on Mechanize?

## Code

```
  def favicon_href
    @favicon_href ||= 
      begin
        page.at(FAVICON_DOM).attributes['href'].value # finding <link> elements
      rescue Exception
        '/favicon.ico' # there are some situation the favicon's not <link>'
      end
  end

  def page
    @page ||= mechanize.get(url)
  end

  def mechanize
    @mechanize ||= Mechanize.new
  end
```

## Error

```
Failure/Error: @page ||= mechanize.get(valid_url(url))

 WebMock::NetConnectNotAllowedError:
   Real HTTP connections are disabled. Unregistered request: GET https://tsaohucn.wordpress.com/ with headers {'Accept'=>'*/*', 'Accept-Charset'=>'ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7', 'Accept-Encoding'=>'gzip,deflate,identity', 'Accept-Language'=>'en-us,en;q=0.5', 'Connection'=>'keep-alive', 'Host'=>'tsaohucn.wordpress.com', 'Keep-Alive'=>'300', 'User-Agent'=>'Mechanize/2.7.5 Ruby/2.3.1p112 (http://github.com/sparklemotion/mechanize/)'}

   You can stub this request with the following snippet:

   stub_request(:get, "https://tsaohucn.wordpress.com/").
     with(headers: {'Accept'=>'*/*', 'Accept-Charset'=>'ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7', 'Accept-Encoding'=>'gzip,deflate,identity', 'Accept-Language'=>'en-us,en;q=0.5', 'Connection'=>'keep-alive', 'Host'=>'tsaohucn.wordpress.com', 'Keep-Alive'=>'300', 'User-Agent'=>'Mechanize/2.7.5 Ruby/2.3.1p112 (http://github.com/sparklemotion/mechanize/)'}).
     to_return(status: 200, body: "", headers: {})

   registered request stubs:

   stub_request(:get, "https://tsaohucn.wordpress.com/").
     with(headers: {'Accept'=>'*/*', 'User-Agent'=>'Ruby'})
   stub_request(:any, "http://api.stripe.com/")
   stub_request(:any, "/api.stripe.com/")

   ============================================================
```

Comment: Protip - start by reading the readme. https://github.com/cheald/manticore#stubbing

Comment: It shows you a sample stub code in the error.

Answer (score 0):

There exists an incompatibility between WebMock and net-http-persistent.

See
https://github.com/bblimke/webmock#connecting-on-nethttpstart

Add

`WebMock.allow_net_connect!(:net_http_connect_on_start => true)`

to your test set up.